# Is there national grade distribution data for introductory service courses?

Tags: undergraduate-education, course-design, usa

I am looking for US average national or state grade distribution data for courses that are typically considered as math service courses: precalculus, calculus 1,2,3, linear algebra, differential equations, and statistics, by various classes of universities (for example  public vs private), by year. Does your university make their data public?

Do you know of any source?

Comment: Related question on academia: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/189924/ . I very much doubt that there is a central source for this.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer  That is what ChatGPT said too! I guess I make a table of data from where I work at and post it here.